# ng-option is not working when option list is returned from $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I Have following code which returns me the list of offers from service in my controller

```
 mosServiceFactory.allOffers().then(function (response) {
            $scope.Offers = response.data.offers;
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.Offers));
 });
```

I am using following code in my HTML to display the list of options in select Tag

```
<select ng-model="offerList" ng-option="offer.campaignName for offer in Offers"></select>
```

the Json response that I get in service is (which is stored in $scope.Offers):

```
[{
        "offerId": "8a1b0cb44e76781e014e767e7b120001",
        "campaignName": "Instant July Offer",
        "campaignDescription": "30% discount on Apple",
        "campaignStartDate": "2015-07-12",
        "campaignEndDate": "2015-07-22",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "enrollmentId": "8a1b0cb44e66dba9014e670a0f8c0001",
        "discount": "30",
        "discountUnit": "Discount %",
        "dateCreated": "2015-07-10",
        "dateModified": null,
        "instantOffId": 1,
        "basketOfferItemId": null,
        "basketOfferQuantity": 0,
        "basketQuantity": 0
    }, {
        "offerId": "8a6804c24e53e4ab014e53fe72770000",
        "campaignName": "July2",
        "campaignDescription": "Weekend Offer from first 100 customers.",
        "campaignStartDate": "2015-07-08",
        "campaignEndDate": "2015-07-11",
        "status": "EXPIRED",
        "enrollmentId": "8a1b0cb44e4e8e2b014e53333d5d0001",
        "discount": "20",
        "discountUnit": "Discount $",
        "dateCreated": "2015-07-03",
        "dateModified": null,
        "instantOffId": 0,
        "basketOfferItemId": null,
        "basketOfferQuantity": 0,
        "basketQuantity": 0
    }, {
        "offerId": "8a1b0cb44e61e491014e622088460003",
        "campaignName": "Weekend discount",
        "campaignDescription": "50% discount",
        "campaignStartDate": "2015-07-06",
        "campaignEndDate": "2015-07-07",
        "status": "INACTIVE",
        "enrollmentId": "8a1b0cb44e61e491014e6207fbaa0001",
        "discount": "50",
        "discountUnit": "Discount %",
        "dateCreated": "2015-07-06",
        "dateModified": "2015-07-06",
        "instantOffId": 0,
        "basketOfferItemId": null,
        "basketOfferQuantity": 0,
        "basketQuantity": 0
    }, {
        "offerId": "8a1b0cb44e766cd5014e766ed37b0000",
        "campaignName": "abc offer",
        "campaignDescription": "50% discount on Apple",
        "campaignStartDate": "2015-07-12",
        "campaignEndDate": "2015-07-17",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "enrollmentId": "8a1b0cb44e61e491014e6207fbaa0001",
        "discount": "50",
        "discountUnit": "Discount %",
        "dateCreated": "2015-07-10",
        "dateModified": null,
        "instantOffId": 1,
        "basketOfferItemId": null,
        "basketOfferQuantity": 0,
        "basketQuantity": 0
    }]
```

Its very similar to this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/fMAGnonoM9JvuIKvnOYU?p=preview

only difference is I am getting list in response.

But somehow, I cant see options in my HTML file !

Comment: You would need to show us the code behind your service in mosServiceFactory.allOffers() - you say it is very similiar to the plunkr, how is it different to the plunker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `ng-options` instead of `ng-option`